# What happens to integer when converted to String

Tags: java, string, integer

I have many times converted a `Integer` to `String` but one thing I didn't understood what happens when an integer is converted to string.

**For E.g:**

if I write `int 1` then it is understood that one is numeric value and it can be used for calculations.

When I write `String.valueOf(1)` how `1` is represented now?

Can any one explain me what will be the Integer state when converted to string?

Thanks for your time

Comment: well, if it is a String, it 'll be "1" -> an actual String, and you won't be able to perform calculations or any other actions you can perform on numerical values on it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Internally, you can think of it being stored as an array of characters, each character representing a digit.

In this case, you would just have an array of one character, with the ASCII value of `'1'`, which is `0x31`.

If you want to know the details of exactly what is inside a Java `String`, you will need to examine the Java source code for `String`.

Comment: Thanks for your response... in this can I compare like this `String.ValueOf(1)=="1"` and what will be my result? `true` or `false`. It means internally its value will be `0x31` and not 1

Comment: @Siva, You should not be using `==` to compare Strings. Use `String.ValueOf(1).equals("1")` and you will get `true` reliably.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response... In this will it compare `ASCII` values or directly compares 1. Sorry for asking so many questions

Comment: @Siva, The string comparison will compare the two strings character by character. In this case it will compare `0x31` with `0x31`, which is the same thing as comparing the character `'1'` to the character `'1'`.

Answer (score 0):

string is nothing more than array of `char`, when you convert a single digit to string it is represented as `char` variable. it's no different then `d` or `|` or `%`. they are just characters which can't be used in any calculations or operations.